# Installing stock ROM - at 65% get error assert failed: write_raw_image("/tmp/oemsbl2.img", "oemsbl2") Status(7), Installation Aborted

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, bootloader, zte-blade

So, that is the problem. I tried to search at google but no luck, only responses were boot.img, and those are not the same. 
updater-script:

```
assert(package_extract_file("boot.img", "/tmp/boot.img"),
       write_raw_image("/tmp/boot.img", "boot"),
       delete("/tmp/boot.img"));
set_oemsbl_size(494552);
assert(package_extract_file("oemsbl.mbn", "/tmp/oemsbl2.img"),
       write_raw_image("/tmp/oemsbl2.img", "oemsbl2"),
       delete("/tmp/oemsbl2.img"));
assert(package_extract_file("amss.mbn", "/tmp/amss.img"),
       write_raw_image("/tmp/amss.img", "amss"),
       delete("/tmp/amss.img"));
assert(package_extract_file("splash.img", "/tmp/splash.img"),
       write_raw_image("/tmp/splash.img", "splash"),
       delete("/tmp/splash.img"));
set_appsbl_size(66328);
assert(package_extract_file("appsboot.mbn", "/tmp/appsbl.img"),
       write_raw_image("/tmp/appsbl.img", "appsbl"),
       delete("/tmp/appsbl.img"));
```

Comment: `Status(7)` in an error meaning that the check for your device (with `assert`) failed. Are you sure you are not trying to install a ROM from another phone/model?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The funny thing is that If I reboot, the ROM boots normally and.the phone is working. Isn't that odd?  I can't find anywhere answer to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it works. It is just a read error, but the installation is complete. On Blade 2, I had the same issue. nandbackup from CWM didn't work - this is a stock rom flashed thru CWM, and it works :)

It is very likely a CWM issue.

Comment: Yes!!!!

I have a blade2 880+ with CWM 4.0.1.5 installed.